# AWS Credentials error: could not load credentials from any providers. ElasticSearch Service node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I was having a problem that I think should be posted on the internet. I may not know the internal issue, but I think I have a solution. Anyway the problem:

I'm hosting an ElasticSearch Service on AWS, and I'm trying to access that service locally and or through my ec2 service hosted on AWS.

But when I try to locally I get this error: `Request Timeout after 30000ms`

When I try it on my ec2 I get this error: `AWS Credentials error: Could not load credentials from any providers`

Here was how I set up the credentials and made the query:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const connectionClass = require('http-aws-es');
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

try {
    var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: "https://some-elastic.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/",
        log: 'error',
        connectionClass: connectionClass,
        amazonES: {
            region: 'us-east-1',
            credentials: new AWS.Credentials('id', 'key')
        }
    });

    elasticClient.indices.delete({
        index: 'foo',
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log("Successful query!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 4));
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
} finally {
}
```

So as stated I kept getting this error. I tried many other variations to pass the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

My vague understanding of the problem is that the `credentials` being set in the amazonES object are being ignored, or that the region isn't being passed along with the credentials. So AWS doesn't know where to search for the credentials.

Anyway here is the solution:

```
    AWS.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: 'key',
        accessKeyId: 'id',
        region: 'your region ex. us-east-1'
    });
    var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: "https://some-elastic.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/",
        log: 'error',
        connectionClass: connectionClass,
        amazonES: {
            credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS'),
        }
    });
```

It's a bit of a buggy situation. I couldn't find this solution anywhere online and I hope it helps someone out who runs into the same errors in the future.